# Laravel/PHP Row Specific Color

Tags: php, laravel

Working in Laravel 4.2, how can I change the color of a single row? I want to make it grey or whatever but I don't know the syntax in order to change it. I don't want to change the entire page, just one row within my project.

```
    {{ HTML::row() }}
    {{ HTML::col(3,3,3,3) }}
    {{ Form::formGroup() }}
    {{ Form::label('RecordID', 'Record ID') }}
    {{ Form::text('RecordID', $Appinfo->RecordID, ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'true', 'readonly']) }}
    {{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
    {{ HTML::closeCol() }}
    {{ Form::formGroup()}}
    {{ HTML::closeRow() }}
```

Comment: You want to change the color of what? The background of an element in the form? The border of an input? Be more detailed when asking questions...

Comment: the background color in this row. I have several rows, but I want to change just one row color at the bottom of my project.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options for how you can achieve this.

**CSS Method**

You can use CSS pseudo selectors to style only the last row:

```
.class-of-parent-element .row:last-child {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```

Please note that this will only work if the row is actually the last element inside its parent.

**Laravel Method**

Assuming that your template already knows that this is the last row (this is unclear from the code sample you supplied) you an assign a class to the row. `HTML::row()` probably accepts an attributes argument, in which case using something like `HTML::row(['class' => 'last-row']);` should allow you to style it through a specific class. Failing this it may be easier to write the row HTML yourself and give it your own class.

```
<div class="row last-row">
    {{ HTML::col(3,3,3,3) }}
    {{ Form::formGroup() }}
    {{ Form::label('RecordID', 'Record ID') }}
    {{ Form::text('RecordID', $Appinfo->RecordID, ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'true', 'readonly']) }}
    {{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
    {{ HTML::closeCol() }}
    {{ Form::formGroup()}}
</div>
```